# How do I get a space as thousands separator in my axis ticks of bokeh graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

With `NumeralTickFormatter(format='0,0')` I was able to get comma as thousands separator for example but I couldn't find a way to use a space.

I also tried to use the `language='fi'` parameter but that didn't seem to help or I  used it the wrong way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know the built in `NumeralTickFormatter` does not support this, since the underlying third party JavaScript library that it is built on does not have any mode to display with spaces. However, Bokeh has a [FuncTickFormatter](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#functickformatter) that allows you to provide your own JS snippet to do whatever formatting you like:

```
from bokeh.models import FuncTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file("formatter.html")

p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500)
p.circle([0, 10], [10, 1000000], size=30)

p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    parts = tick.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
    return parts.join(".");
""")

show(p)
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick answer and solution.